# How to include spaces in arguments while calling R from a batchfile

Tags: r, batch-file, arguments

The following is my batch file:

```
D:\R-software\R-3.2.3\bin\R.exe CMD BATCH "--args Model A,Model B,Model C parameter2 parameter3" C:\Users\TEMP.INDIA\Desktop\prediction_test.r C:\Users\TEMP.INDIA\Desktop\predi.out &
pause
```

Here, `Model A,Model B,Model C` is my first parameter along with with two others.
But it takes Model as the first parameter and A as the second parameter.
What separator can I use between parameters and how can I group them?

Comment: Can you use quotes for each parameter?

Comment: nope
It takes quote just as any other character of the argument

Comment: Have you tried [using carets as escape characters?](http://superuser.com/questions/279008/how-do-i-escape-spaces-in-command-line-in-windows-without-using-quotation-marks)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4808574/2836621

Comment: Why is there an `&` at the end of your `R.exe` command line?